# Simple function and changing of values

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im working in node, but i think this is mostly pure a Javascript question. 
Lets say i have a simple object like this:

```
var simpleObject = {
  decimal: ' 314,2351 ', 
  id: '324fgfdhf34',
  mail: 'anders@JEJR.se'
  something: 'whateever...'
}
```

Now I want to create a simple sanitize function, that takes a object[property] as argument, change it, and save it directly. I want to place this function in a node module and require it.

Right now i have this function (and some more...) in a module which i require in my app and binds to a variable name "purify"

```
exports.toFloat = function(str) {
  str = str.replace(',', '.');
  str = parseFloat(str);
  return str;
}
```

And in my app I can write this to use the function:

```
simpleObject.decimal = purify.toFloat(simpleObject.decimal)
```

but i would like to be able to write something more shorter... like this:

```
purify.toFloat(simpleObject.decial)
```

... and have the value changed and saved directly.

**Question:** How do i change the code above so I can write this and have it work:

```
purify.toFloat(simpleObject.decial)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't exactly call it as you want, because when you pass the parameter as `simpleObject.decimal` you lost the reference to `simpleObject`. You can do this instead, which is quite close:

```
exports.toFloat = function(obj, propName) {
  obj[propName] = parseFloat(obj[propName].replace(',', '.'));
}
// Usage:
purify.toFloat(simpleObject, 'decimal');
```

Comment: Tibos  , he does lose the reference but he only need to change inside value. not giving the reference new address.

Comment: I mean : `var a={v:1};

function kk(p)
{
  p.v=4;
}

kk(a);
alert(a.v); //will alert 4`

Comment: `kk(p.v)` -> inside `kk` you have no reference towards `p`. It's identical to `var temp = p.v; kk(temp)` as `temp` doesn't have a reference to `p`.

Comment: The OP wants to call the function with the only argument `object.property` and at the same time change `object.property` to another value inside the function. The function has no reference to `object`, so he cannot set `object.property` to a new value. If you have an answer closer to what the OP wants, by all means post it. I will be glad to learn something new today.

Comment: _"so he cannot set object.property to a new value"_ -----thats wrong. it passes by value so there is another (new) reference to the SAME  memory location of the original object. so if you do (inside the function) `X.prop=` it DOES change the original value of the prop of original object.BUT  if you do inside the function : `X= {}` - well that's another very different thing and it wont be reflected to the original object.

Comment: You gave the exact same solution, which is quite different than what you are arguing in these comments.

Comment: I guess  that I just don't understand you. nevermind.:-) ( I just said that he wants to change the inner value of the original obj)

Comment: LOL . I even didnt look at your solution and I've just seen myne is the same.  deleting myne. :-) p.s. +1